# COBOL XML GENERATE using tags and attributes

Tags: cobol

I am trying to create a XML file from a COBOL program using the `XML GENERATE` statement.

COBOL structure :

```
    01 EMPLOYEE.
       05 ID PIC X(1).
       05 NAME PIC X(10).
       05 DEPT PIC X(10).
```

`XML GENERATE` will create all sub elements

```xml
<employee>
  <id>1</id> 
  <name>Someone</name>
  <dept>Marketing</dept>
</employee>
```

If I use `XML GENERATE WITH ATTRIBUTES` Function, 
It will create all attributes :

```xml
<employee id="1" name="Someone" dept="Marketing"> 
</employee>
```

Is there a way we can somehow indicate that some sub group items should be attributes and some sub elements:

```xml
<employee id="1">
  <name>Someone</name>
  <dept>Marketing</dept>
</employee>
```

and if yes, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way we can somehow indicate that some sub group items should be attributes and some sub elements

Answer: yes.

See IBM's docs on [XML GENERATE statement](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS6SG3_6.2.0/com.ibm.cobol62.ent.doc/PGandLR/ref/rlpsxmlg.html), you can adjust the type of a single data-item with the `TYPE` phrase, which may specify multiple items:

```
           XML GENERATE variable-name
               FROM EMPLOYEE
               TYPE OF ID                 IS ATTRIBUTE
                       secondary-variable IS ATTRIBUTE
```

Note: as IBM's docs [XML element name and attribute name formation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS6SG3_6.2.0/com.ibm.cobol62.ent.doc/PGandLR/ref/rlpsxmlge.html) says:

> The exact mixed-case spelling of data-names from the data description entry is retained.

You likely want to change the COBOL variable names to all lower case or use the `NAME` phrase for all data-entries (at least if you expect it to be all in lower case as in your "target sample").